# Android SDK and AVD Manager Error: File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

Initially, I installed only Android API 12. But now, I'm trying to install other available packages and it displays:

```
Downloading SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-3.0_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.2_r02-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.1_r02-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-1.6_r03-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-1.5_r04-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-3.1_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-3.0_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 38):

> Blockquote Try starting the SDK Manager with Administrator privileges. Then it should work.

Tried and confirmed, admin priviledges required.

Next time, try installing the SDK on a path that doesn't require privileged access rights (Program Files does). You could also edit the settings of the SDK install path to give write access to the user you log in as.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but how do you edit the settings for the SDK install path on Win7?

Answer (score 20):

Try starting the SDK Manager with Administrator privileges. Then it should work.

Comment: Open the android Sdk folder right click on sdk manager run as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked with Administrator priviledges, but:

- If I run SDK Manager from Eclipse, it still doesn't work (even with admin).
- If I run SDK Manager exe file, it works.

Answer (score 4):

please goto start menu, locate SDK manager, right click and "run as administrator" and it wil work.

Answer (score 4):

open android SDK folder , right click on SDK manager run as administrator then install what do you want

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem I tried to run SDK Manager with Administrator privileges but it did not work: it wasn't able to fetch the packages.
I solved the problem running Eclipse as Administrator and starting the SDK Manager from there

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and "Run with admin privileges" weren't enough !

I solved it by resintalling the sdk :

1. Go to the [Android SDK website](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and download the stand-alone SDK manager
2. You can install it for all users (will always require admin privileges) or only for you. That's how you want.
3. Then the update should work ! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem, and it had to do with permissions.

Find your android folder (default is in program files). Right click on the folder and go to properties. Look under the security tab and then find the edit button. Change the permissions to allow full control with User.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and "Run with admin privileges" , it worked